# Getting tkinter.Widget bindings

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, callback, widget

Is there a way to get the default binding of `tk.Widget` class and then call it?

I need to do this because I need to call the default binding before my custom binding. It is called as the last by default.

So what I want to do is: bind my widget to my own callback, get the default binding function, call the default binding function, call my fuction (custom binding)

Comment: what do you mean by default binding?

Comment: Is your real go to get the bindings or is the real goal simply to reverse the order in which they are processed?

Comment: My real goal is to reverse them; default binding is the one for example on a listbox when you click on it and it selects the item. I need to check the selection after each click.

Comment: If your real problem is handling listbox selection, there's a special binding for that.

Comment: Oh wait, I am using this in my other listbox... I am so dumb :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply reverse the order that the bindings are processed, you can do that by changing the binding tags without needing to know what the actual bindings are. The tags are what determines the order that events are processed. By default the value is the widget, the widget class, the toplevel window, and then "all".

The following example changes the order so that the class binding (`"Entry"`) is handled before the binding of the widget:

```
import tkinter as tk
...
e = tk.Entry(...)
e.bindtags((
    e.winfo_class(), 
    str(e), 
    e.winfo_toplevel(), 
    "all")
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `"."` makes my window iconify when i click my listbox. The window has `overrideredirect(True)` set.

Comment: @JakubBláha: are your widgets inside a `Toplevel`?

Comment: My widgets are inside a `tk.Toplevel`.

Comment: @JakubBláha: I've updated my example. Instead of `"."` you need to get the internal name of the `Toplevel` widget by using `winfo_toplevel()`.